# Is it possible to list student members of an inactive (education class) team?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-teams, microsoft-graph-edu

I'm creating education class teams via MS Graph API. I create an education class and then a team for that class using the method described here: [Create a team from group](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/team-post?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#example-4-create-a-team-from-group).

Teams remain inactive until the teacher is ready to set up and activate the team. All good.

But until a team is activated, when I [List members](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/team-list-members?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) of a team, non-owner members (students) are **not** included in the response.

Is anyone aware of an option to include the students in the response? Note that if I [List members of the Education Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/educationclass-list-members?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) then the students are included, but that does not give me the team membership-id required to [Remove members from team](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/team-delete-members?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http).

Comment: Being said that you may want to consider filing an user voice, so that Microsoft can consider implementing it as new feature. Here's the link - https://microsoftgraph.uservoice.com/forums/920506-microsoft-graph-feature-requests?category_id=359587

Comment: I've posted the idea in Teamwork category: https://microsoftgraph.uservoice.com/forums/920506-microsoft-graph-feature-requests/suggestions/41962264-list-all-members-of-an-inactive-team. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this with Microsoft Graph API at this point. Uservoice is raised on [this](https://microsoftgraph.uservoice.com/forums/920506-microsoft-graph-feature-requests/suggestions/41962264-list-all-members-of-an-inactive-team).

Answer (score 0):

One bit of clarification, the Team isn't "inactive" so much as it hasn't been fully provisioned yet.  When creating a Class, it adds a Team provisioning option. This simple queues it up for provisioning when the owner opens the UI. Until then it is simply a Group.

Since there isn't a fully provisioned Team, there isn't a Team to remove members from. What there is, however, is a Group/Class directory object. [Removing a member from the Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/educationclass-post-members?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) ([or the Group](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/group-delete-members?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)) will result in that member not getting added to the Team if/when the actual provisioning occurs.